# react router replace param with string

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, replace, react-router

Ok, so I want to replace the /:id part of this with a string.

```
            {
            ...SiteDashboard,
            path: "/Sites/:id",
            exact: true
        },
```

needs to be...

```
        {
            ...SiteDashboard,
            path: "/Sites/SiteDashboard",
            exact: true
        },
```

I have tried the following with replace...

```
const string ="id"

            {
                ...SiteDashboard,
                path: string.replace('/Sites'+/:[0-9?]+/g, "Site Dashboard"),
                exact: true
            },
```

any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you want to redirect all requests to`:/id` to `/SiteDashboard` ?

Comment: @RashadKokash yes so that that id parameter (number) is hidden and replaced in my route with "Site Dashborad". So basicaly check for any integer and replace with that string.

Comment: I currently use /Sites/:id which returns for eg. /Sites/24

Comment: What would you do if someone just visited /Sites/SiteDashboard, what content would you load since you don't have the id. Also it seems like you want the id param to be in memory ony

Comment: In your Dashboard component put this in `componentDidMount` or in `useEffect` .. `window.history.replaceState({}, null, '/Sites/SiteDashboard')`

Comment: @RashadKokash this works ok on that page but there are many routes coming from SiteDashboard and breadcrumbs so would need to add this to all views. I need to do it directly in the routes file. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to pass the id as a param? 
Perhaps you can set the route to simply "/Sites/SiteDashboard" and pass the id this way:

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/Sites/SiteDashboard"
  render={props => (
    <SiteDashboard
      {...props}
      id={id}
    />
  )}
/>
```

Comment: I get the id from a datatable an push like this. see commented for how I previously did it. tried this but not sure how to pass this back. handleRowClicked = row => {
        //this.props.history.push(`/Sites/${row.id}`);
        this.props.history.push({
            pathname: '/Sites/SiteDashboard',
            state: { id: row.id }
          })
    };

Comment: Pass it back to where? Seems correct to me, on SiteDashboard you can access it with this.props.location.state.id

Comment: when i do the push, im getting the id but in router i keep getting ReferenceError: id is not defined

Comment: render: props => <SiteDashboard.component {...props} id={id} />

Comment: on SiteDashboard im getting id like this in ComponentDidMount const siteId = this.props.location.state.id;

Comment: seems to be working now using this in route. thanks for your help. render: props => <SiteDashboard.component {...props} id={props.location.state.id} />